Unable to Connect to Recovery Server During macOS Installation - Need Assistance
I am trying to upgrade my HDD to SAMSUNG SSD 980 NVME M2
My Last MacOS was Monterey 12.7.1
Macbook AIR 13 inch 2017
Processor : 1.8Ghz Dual Core Intel Core i5.
I'm currently experiencing difficulties while trying to install macOS on my MacBook Air 2017. Whenever I attempt to connect to the recovery server during the installation process, I encounter an error message stating 'The recovery server could not be contacted.' I've tried troubleshooting steps such as checking my internet connection, resetting NVRAM/PRAM.but the issue persists. Can someone please provide guidance on how to resolve this issue and successfully complete the macOS installation? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!"
Installation Log Details :
> Apr 27 12:19:20 localhost Installer Progress[197]: Progress UI App Starting

> Apr 27 12:19:21 localhost opendirectoryd[202]: [default] Failed to open file <private> [2: No > such file or directory]
> Apr 27 12:19:21 localhost opendirectoryd[202]: [default] Failed to open file <private> [2: No > such file or directory]
> Apr 27 12:19:21 localhost opendirectoryd[202]: [default] Failed to open file <private> [2: No > such file or directory]
> Apr 27 12:19:42 MacBook-Air mobileassetd[341]: SUPreferenceManager: Service connection > invalidated!
> Apr 27 12:19:42 MacBook-Air mobileassetd[341]: SUPreferenceManager: Connection proxy failure with error:Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.softwareupdated was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 3 - No such process." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.softwareupdated was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 3 - No such process.}
> Apr 27 12:19:42 MacBook-Air mobileassetd[341]: SUPreferenceManager: Service connection invalidated!
> Apr 27 12:19:42 MacBook-Air mobileassetd[341]: SUPreferenceManager: Connection proxy failure with error:Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.softwareupdated was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 3 - No such process." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.softwareupdated was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 3 - No such process.}
> Apr 27 12:19:42 MacBook-Air mobileassetd[341]: SUPreferenceManager: Service connection invalidated!
> Apr 27 12:19:42 MacBook-Air mobileassetd[341]: SUPreferenceManager: Connection proxy failure with error:Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.softwareupdated was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 3 - No such process." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.softwareupdated was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 3 - No such process.}
> Apr 27 12:19:54 MacBook-Air Installer Progress[197]: IASGetCurrentInstallPhaseList: Unable to get phases
> Apr 27 12:19:54 MacBook-Air Installer Progress[197]: IASGetCurrentInstallPhase: Unable to get the current phase name
> Apr 27 12:19:54 MacBook-Air Installer Progress[197]: currentPhase = "(null)", phases = (null)
> Apr 27 12:19:54 MacBook-Air Installer Progress[197]: Progress app is loading…
> Apr 27 12:19:54 MacBook-Air Installer Progress[197]: Progress app is running with no progress set
> Apr 27 12:19:54 MacBook-Air Installer Progress[197]: Progress app is running…
> Apr 27 12:19:55 MacBook-Air launchprogresswindow[382]: ISAP: Show progress UI called
> Apr 27 12:19:55 MacBook-Air Installer Progress[197]: Connected processes {
        "9FC33720-33DC-44C3-BF07-26C5AC1A9C97" =     {
            "Phase Name" = "Launch Progress Window";
            "Process ID" = 382;
            UUID = "9FC33720-33DC-44C3-BF07-26C5AC1A9C97";
        };
    }
> Apr 27 12:19:55 MacBook-Air Installer Progress[197]: Connected processes {
        "9FC33720-33DC-44C3-BF07-26C5AC1A9C97" =     {
            CompletionHandlerKey = "<_NSMallocBlock_: 0x600002f19310>";
            "Phase Name" = "Launch Progress Window";
            "Process ID" = 382;
            UUID = "9FC33720-33DC-44C3-BF07-26C5AC1A9C97";
        };
    }
> Apr 27 12:19:55 MacBook-Air Installer Progress[197]: IASGetCurrentInstallPhaseList: Unable to get phases
> Apr 27 12:19:55 MacBook-Air Installer Progress[197]: IASGetCurrentInstallPhase: Unable to get the current phase name
> Apr 27 12:19:55 MacBook-Air Installer Progress[197]: currentPhase = "(null)", phases = (null)
> Apr 27 12:19:55 MacBook-Air Installer Progress[197]: Showing Progress UI
> Apr 27 12:19:55 MacBook-Air Installer Progress[197]: There are 0 window(s) and 1 display(s), 1 window(s) will be added
> Apr 27 12:19:55 MacBook-Air Installer Progress[197]: IOProgressColorTheme is set to 1
> Apr 27 12:19:55 MacBook-Air Installer Progress[197]: Created a window at {{0, 0}, {1440, 900}}
> Apr 27 12:19:56 MacBook-Air Installer Progress[197]: Status is ""
> Apr 27 12:19:56 MacBook-Air Installer Progress[197]: Alternate status is ""
> Apr 27 12:19:56 MacBook-Air Installer Progress[197]: no background for progress added because:
> Apr 27 12:19:56 MacBook-Air Installer Progress[197]:        and / or NOT booting from EFI loginwindow
> Apr 27 12:19:56 MacBook-Air Installer Progress[197]: Setting window alpha values to 1.0
> Apr 27 12:19:56 MacBook-Air Installer Progress[197]: Ordering windows front
> Apr 27 12:19:56 MacBook-Air Language Chooser[383]: System doesn't have bridgeOS
> Apr 27 12:19:58 MacBook-Air Installer Progress[197]: Connected processes {
        "9FC33720-33DC-44C3-BF07-26C5AC1A9C97" =     {
            CompletionHandlerKey = "<_NSMallocBlock_: 0x600002f19310>";
            "Phase Name" = "Launch Progress Window";
            "Process ID" = 382;
            UUID = "9FC33720-33DC-44C3-BF07-26C5AC1A9C97";
        };
        "C4A83D6E-A3E1-4155-A063-80A7A7D600B5" =     {
            "Phase Name" = "Language Chooser";
            "Process ID" = 383;
            UUID = "C4A83D6E-A3E1-4155-A063-80A7A7D600B5";
        };
    }
> Apr 27 12:19:58 MacBook-Air Installer Progress[197]: Connected processes {
        "9FC33720-33DC-44C3-BF07-26C5AC1A9C97" =     {
            CompletionHandlerKey = "<_NSMallocBlock_: 0x600002f19310>";
            "Phase Name" = "Launch Progress Window";
            "Process ID" = 382;
            UUID = "9FC33720-33DC-44C3-BF07-26C5AC1A9C97";
        };
        "C4A83D6E-A3E1-4155-A063-80A7A7D600B5" =     {
            CompletionHandlerKey = "<_NSMallocBlock_: 0x600002f16440>";
            "Phase Name" = "Language Chooser";
            "Process ID" = 383;
            UUID = "C4A83D6E-A3E1-4155-A063-80A7A7D600B5";
        };
    }
> Apr 27 12:19:59 MacBook-Air Language Chooser[383]: Setup: Factory cable attached: 0
> Apr 27 12:19:59 MacBook-Air Language Chooser[383]: SCNetworkSetEstablishDefaultConfiguration returned 0 error Success!
> Apr 27 12:19:59 MacBook-Air Language Chooser[383]: reachability flags returned: 2
> Apr 27 12:19:59 MacBook-Air Language Chooser[383]: network is reachable
> Apr 27 12:19:59 MacBook-Air Language Chooser[383]: network reachable?: 1
> Apr 27 12:20:00 MacBook-Air Language Chooser[383]: System doesn't have bridgeOS
> Apr 27 12:20:00 MacBook-Air Language Chooser[383]: Could not read prev-lang:kbd to set keyboard.
> Apr 27 12:20:00 MacBook-Air Language Chooser[383]: ISAP: hide progress UI called
> Apr 27 12:20:00 MacBook-Air Installer Progress[197]: Hiding Progress UI
> Apr 27 12:20:00 MacBook-Air Installer Progress[197]: Setting window alpha values to 0.0
> Apr 27 12:20:00 MacBook-Air Installer Progress[197]: Ordering windows out
> Apr 27 12:20:05 MacBook-Air Installer Progress[197]: Unable to quit because there are connected processes
> Apr 27 12:20:05 MacBook-Air Installer Progress[197]: Connected processes {
        "9FC33720-33DC-44C3-BF07-26C5AC1A9C97" =     {
            CompletionHandlerKey = "<_NSMallocBlock_: 0x600002f19310>";
            "Phase Name" = "Launch Progress Window";
            "Process ID" = 382;
            UUID = "9FC33720-33DC-44C3-BF07-26C5AC1A9C97";
        };
        "C4A83D6E-A3E1-4155-A063-80A7A7D600B5" =     {
            CompletionHandlerKey = "<_NSMallocBlock_: 0x600002f16440>";
            "Phase Name" = "Language Chooser";
            "Process ID" = 383;
            UUID = "C4A83D6E-A3E1-4155-A063-80A7A7D600B5";
        };
    }
> Apr 27 12:20:16 MacBook-Air Language Chooser[383]: System doesn't have bridgeOS
> Apr 27 12:20:16 MacBook-Air Language Chooser[383]: System doesn't have bridgeOS
> Apr 27 12:20:17 MacBook-Air OSIESpringboard[397]: System doesn't have bridgeOS
> Apr 27 12:20:17 MacBook-Air OSIESpringboard[397]: ISAP: hide progress UI called
> Apr 27 12:20:17 MacBook-Air Installer Progress[197]: Connected processes {
        "3196688D-AA6A-4FF1-B464-98FA56CA6417" =     {
            "Phase Name" = "Install Springboard";
            "Process ID" = 397;
            UUID = "3196688D-AA6A-4FF1-B464-98FA56CA6417";
        };
        "9FC33720-33DC-44C3-BF07-26C5AC1A9C97" =     {
            CompletionHandlerKey = "<_NSMallocBlock_: 0x600002f19310>";
            "Phase Name" = "Launch Progress Window";
            "Process ID" = 382;
            UUID = "9FC33720-33DC-44C3-BF07-26C5AC1A9C97";
        };
        "C4A83D6E-A3E1-4155-A063-80A7A7D600B5" =     {
            CompletionHandlerKey = "<_NSMallocBlock_: 0x600002f16440>";
            "Phase Name" = "Language Chooser";
            "Process ID" = 383;
            UUID = "C4A83D6E-A3E1-4155-A063-80A7A7D600B5";
        };
    }
> Apr 27 12:20:17 MacBook-Air Installer Progress[197]: Connected processes {
        "3196688D-AA6A-4FF1-B464-98FA56CA6417" =     {
            CompletionHandlerKey = "<_NSMallocBlock_: 0x600002f11900>";
            "Phase Name" = "Install Springboard";
            "Process ID" = 397;
            UUID = "3196688D-AA6A-4FF1-B464-98FA56CA6417";
        };
        "9FC33720-33DC-44C3-BF07-26C5AC1A9C97" =     {
            CompletionHandlerKey = "<_NSMallocBlock_: 0x600002f19310>";
            "Phase Name" = "Launch Progress Window";
            "Process ID" = 382;
            UUID = "9FC33720-33DC-44C3-BF07-26C5AC1A9C97";
        };
        "C4A83D6E-A3E1-4155-A063-80A7A7D600B5" =     {
            CompletionHandlerKey = "<_NSMallocBlock_: 0x600002f16440>";
            "Phase Name" = "Language Chooser";
            "Process ID" = 383;
            UUID = "C4A83D6E-A3E1-4155-A063-80A7A7D600B5";
        };
    }
> Apr 27 12:20:17 MacBook-Air Installer Progress[197]: Connected processes {
        "3196688D-AA6A-4FF1-B464-98FA56CA6417" =     {
            CompletionHandlerKey = "<_NSMallocBlock_: 0x600002f117c0>";
            "Phase Name" = "Install Springboard";
            "Process ID" = 397;
            UUID = "3196688D-AA6A-4FF1-B464-98FA56CA6417";
        };
        "9FC33720-33DC-44C3-BF07-26C5AC1A9C97" =     {
            CompletionHandlerKey = "<_NSMallocBlock_: 0x600002f19310>";
            "Phase Name" = "Launch Progress Window";
            "Process ID" = 382;
            UUID = "9FC33720-33DC-44C3-BF07-26C5AC1A9C97";
        };
        "C4A83D6E-A3E1-4155-A063-80A7A7D600B5" =     {
            CompletionHandlerKey = "<_NSMallocBlock_: 0x600002f16440>";
            "Phase Name" = "Language Chooser";
            "Process ID" = 383;
            UUID = "C4A83D6E-A3E1-4155-A063-80A7A7D600B5";
        };
    }
> Apr 27 12:20:17 MacBook-Air Installer Progress[197]: Connected processes {
        "9FC33720-33DC-44C3-BF07-26C5AC1A9C97" =     {
            CompletionHandlerKey = "<_NSMallocBlock_: 0x600002f19310>";
            "Phase Name" = "Launch Progress Window";
            "Process ID" = 382;
            UUID = "9FC33720-33DC-44C3-BF07-26C5AC1A9C97";
        };
        "C4A83D6E-A3E1-4155-A063-80A7A7D600B5" =     {
            CompletionHandlerKey = "<_NSMallocBlock_: 0x600002f16440>";
            "Phase Name" = "Language Chooser";
            "Process ID" = 383;
            UUID = "C4A83D6E-A3E1-4155-A063-80A7A7D600B5";
        };
    }
Apr 27 12:20:18 MacBook-Air OSIESpringboard[397]: Safari Preferences Container: Does not exist. -- Error:21
Apr 27 12:20:18 MacBook-Air Language Chooser[383]: System doesn't have bridgeOS
> Apr 27 12:20:20 MacBook-Air KeyRecoveryAssistant[399]: Running KeyRecoveryAssistant-140 (/AppleInternal/Library/BuildRoots/a0876c02-1788-11ed-b9c4-96898e02b808/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/KeyRecoveryAssistant)
> Apr 27 12:20:21 MacBook-Air KeyRecoveryAssistant[399]: Mode: Authentication
> Apr 27 12:20:21 MacBook-Air KeyRecoveryAssistant[399]: Device does not support activation.
> Apr 27 12:20:25 MacBook-Air KeyRecoveryAssistant[399]: APFSVolumeGetSiDPState for > volume:/dev/disk2s1 (SKAPFSDisk { APFS UUID: 04606E26-B15A-485F-99E8-B7DF4836EC08, CONTAINER > UUID: 6CF79BCA-34C8-47F3-B943-67529AC357E2, DISK ID: disk2s1 ENCRYPTED: NO } ) returned error: 22
> Apr 27 12:20:25 MacBook-Air KeyRecoveryAssistant[399]: Machine fv auth required:0
> Apr 27 12:20:25 MacBook-Air KeyRecoveryAssistant[399]: setSystemToRecover: unset volume
> Apr 27 12:20:25 MacBook-Air KeyRecoveryAssistant[399]: Hiding APFS volume 'MAC', no users on > volume
> Apr 27 12:20:25 MacBook-Air KeyRecoveryAssistant[399]: Machine internal system count:0, has internal FV:0
> Apr 27 12:20:25 MacBook-Air KeyRecoveryAssistant[399]: Auth mode, but no internal FV volumes and activation lock isn't enabled. Just exit
> Apr 27 12:20:25 MacBook-Air KeyRecoveryAssistant[399]: Has Authenticated: YES
> Apr 27 12:20:25 MacBook-Air KeyRecoveryAssistant[399]: Enabling AMFI permissive trustcache
> Apr 27 12:20:25 MacBook-Air KeyRecoveryAssistant[399]: Quitting after successful auth...
> Apr 27 12:22:39 MacBook-Air InstallAssistant[440]: No compatibility bundle on this version of macOS. Will assume compatible.


Make a bootable USB, boot from it, install the OS from it.
